# Function with two objects as arguments

Tags: c++, templates, pass-by-reference

I have a base class `Shape` and some other derived classes like `Circle`, `Rectangle` and so on. I would like to pass two objects to a function `getDistance(object1, object2)` to calculate the distance between the two objects.

My question is, how should this function be declared and implemented? Do you think I should use `template` since I might pass two objects from two different classes? If so, how would the `template` look like?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually you would use a **pure virtual on your base class**. You already have inheritance from Shape, so templates are overkill for this problem.

Add a **virtual GetPosition()** to your base Shape class and make getDistance() take two **Shape pointers** (or references). For example:

```
class Shape
{
public:
    ~virtual Shape() {}  // Make sure you have a virtual destructor on base

    // Assuming you have a Position struct/class
    virtual Position GetPosition() const = 0;
};

class Circle : public Shape
{
public:
    virtual Position GetPosition() const;  // Implemented elsewhere
};

class Rectangle : public Shape
{
public:
    virtual Position GetPosition() const;  // Implemented elsewhere
};

float getDistance(const Shape& one, const Shape& Two)
{
    // Calculate distance here by calling one.GetPosition() etc
}

// And to use it...
Circle circle;
Rectangle rectangle;
getDistance(circle, rectangle);
```

EDIT: Pawel Zubrycki is correct - added virtual destructor on base class for good measure. ;)

Comment: Wow, that's fantastic idea. My class is slightly different from what you posted, but your point gave me led me to the solution. Thanks a lot Scotty :)

Comment: There should be virtual destructor in `Shape` class.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a template:

```
template<class S, class T> getDistance(const S& object1, const T& object2) {
```

As long as both objects have the same function or variables (ie. x and y) to calculate the distance.

Otherwise you can use inheritance:

```
getDistance(const Shape& object1, const Shape& object2)
```

as long as the  Shape class forces a getPosition like function:

```
getPosition() = 0; (in Shape)
```

I would suggest inheritance because it will be cleaner and easier to understand and control errors, at the expense of a tiny amout of speed.

Answer (score 0):

The other option is to use parametric polymorphism:

```
struct Position {
    float x, y;
};

class Circle {
public:
    Position GetPosition() const;  // Implemented elsewhere
};

class Rectangle {
public:
    Position GetPosition() const;  // Implemented elsewhere
};

float getDistance(const Position &oneP, const Position twoP); // Implemented elsewhere

template<class K, class U>
float getDistance(const K& one, const U& two) {
    return getDistance(one.GetPosition(), two.GetPosition());
}
```